# 共有カスタマイズファイルを自動読み込みしたい

Tags: ijcad

IJCAD Mechanical 2022の共有カスタマイズファイルに対応するレジストリに
自作のCUIXファイルパスを登録するVB.Netのプログラムを作成しました。

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\IntelliJapan\IJCAD Mechanical\R22\ja-jp\Profiles\IJCADMech2022Pro\General Configuration：EnterpriseMenuFile**
※上記レジストリに自作のCUIXファイルパスを登録を行っています。

プログラム実行後、
IJCAD Mechanical 2022を起動し、オプションを見ると
共有カスタマイズファイルが自作のCUIXファイルパスになっていることは確認できました。

ただ、リボンには変化がなく、
標準コマンド「CUI」コマンドで「ユーザーカスタマイズ」画面を開き、読み込んだCUIXファイルを確認しても
共有カスタマイズファイルに設定した自作のCUIXファイルが存在しません。

プログラムでレジストリ登録する
共有カスタマイズファイルの設定方法では、
CUIXファイルの自動読み込みされないのでしょうか？

共有カスタマイズファイルに設定したCUIXファイルを
自動読み込みする方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

□環境
OS：Windows 10
IJCAD：IJCAD Mechanical 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 共有カスタマイズファイルに設定したCUIXファイルを
> 自動読み込みする方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

質問の方法で、レジストリを設定するプログラム的には正常に設定できていると思います。
また、同様の設定は下記のAPIからでも可能です。
GrxCAD.Interop.GcadPreferences.Files.EnterpriseMenuFileプロパティ

> プログラムでレジストリ登録する
> 共有カスタマイズファイルの設定方法では、
> CUIXファイルの自動読み込みされないのでしょうか？

OPTIONSコマンドのファイルタブから共有カスタマイズファイルの設定を行った場合でも、リボンには変化がなく、「CUI」コマンドの「ユーザーカスタマイズ」画面に追加されませんでした。
よって、プログラムの問題ではなく、共有カスタマイズファイルの機能自体がうまく機能していないのかもしれません。